# How to setup jbpm without schema owner account?

Tags: hibernate, database-schema, jbpm

I am setting up JBPM 6.5 and Kie-Server with WildFly 10.1.0, when use database schema account, everything is fine, but when I change to another account (with select, insert, update delete privilege) then table not found error throw during startup,

Although I already set default_schema in jbpm-console.war\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml:

and -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.schema=jbpmdev

Is JBPM can only run with schema owner account?

I find workaround by setting up logon trigger or create synonym at database side, but it look abnormal, anyone can setup JBPM without use schema owner account?

below is the error:

```
2017-07-17 12:15:40,588 ERROR [org.dashbuilder.dataprovider.sql.JDBCUtils] (default task-24) SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM PROCESSINSTANCELOG) WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
...
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 318, Sql = SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT T.ACTIVATIONTIME, T.ACTUALOWNER, T.CREATEDBY, T.CREATEDON, T.DEPLOYMENTID, T.DESCRIPTION, T.DUEDATE, T.NAME, T.PARENTID, T.PRIORITY, T.PROCESSID, T.PROCESSINSTANCEID, T.PROCESSSESSIONID, T.STATUS, T.TASKID, T.WORKITEMID, OE.ID FROM AUDITTASKIMPL T, PEOPLEASSIGNMENTS_POTOWNERS PO, ORGANIZATIONALENTITY OE WHERE T.TASKID = PO.TASK_ID AND PO.ENTITY_ID = OE.ID) "dbSQL") WHERE ROWNUM <= 1, OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT T.ACTIVATIONTIME, T.ACTUALOWNER, T.CREATEDBY, T.CREATEDON, T.DEPLOYMENTID, T.DESCRIPTION, T.DUEDATE, T.NAME, T.PARENTID, T.PRIORITY, T.PROCESSID, T.PROCESSINSTANCEID, T.PROCESSSESSIONID, T.STATUS, T.TASKID, T.WORKITEMID, OE.ID FROM AUDITTASKIMPL T, PEOPLEASSIGNMENTS_POTOWNERS PO, ORGANIZATIONALENTITY OE WHERE T.TASKID = PO.TASK_ID AND PO.ENTITY_ID = OE.ID) "dbSQL") WHERE ROWNUM <= 1, Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: It might be hibernate issue.
hibernate-mapping's schema is ignored:
 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10678

Comment: Can you try creating jBPM tables with DDL script ?

Comment: jbpm tables were created by DDL script.
I had issue jira:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-6226?_sscc=t

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jbpm-setup/UYDFXEopxBQ